# How to Add Dynamic Column in listview Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem i want to add Colomn ( Dynamic using C #) in listview in Wpf how can i achive it and why we using grid view inside Listview in Wpf plz help me out

thanks shashank tyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListView` can present data in a variety of formats. This is based on it's `View` property. By setting the view to `GridView`. you are telling the listview that you wish to present your data in the gridview format.

AS for the creation of columns
[MSDN has a good tutorial on how to do this programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx).

Basically you'll just need to create the gridview dynamically and then assign it to the View property of the listview

Hope it helps. - Val